# pick up even numbers from a list

Tags: prolog

Define the rule filterevens(LST0, LST1). This rule describes how the list LST0 relates to the list LST1, which consists of only even elements of LST0.

I need to pick up the even numbers from a list, And I got this:

```
filterevens([],[]).
filterevens([H|T],R):-
    (  0 is mod(H,2) 
    -> R = [H|T2]
    ;  R = T2
    ),
    filterevens(T,T2).
```

when the input is

```
?- filterevens( [2,4] ,A).
```

it can give me the correct answer. But if I tried

```
?- filterevens(A,[2,4]).
```

it cause an error. So what should I do so that I can do both in just one rule?

Comment: Similar (if not identical) to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71596567/prolog-check-if-second-list-has-all-even-numbers-from-the-first-list/71599018#71599018

Comment: What should the behavior be for `filterevens( A , [2,4] ).` be, exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing the cases out in full without `;` is enough for it to work in the basic case:

```
filterevens([], []).

filterevens([H|T], [H|TEvens]):-
    0 is H mod 2,
    filterevens(T, TEvens).

filterevens([H|T], TEvens):-
    M is H mod 2,
    dif(M, 0),
    filterevens(T, TEvens).
```

Then:

```
?- filterevens(A, [2,4]).
A = [2, 4]
```

The general case, `A` could be any length `[1,2,1,4]` or `[1,1,1,1,1,2,4]`, generating all possible lists with `2`, `4` as the only even numbers would be more difficult. You could build something with the `clpfd` library if you could constrain the members of the list, e.g. to "positive integers between 1 and 1,000".